# How do I disconnect a OkHttp3 sse connection?

Tags: okhttp

## Problem:

I'm trying to create a client that can receive events from a server using SSE (server-sent events) and I'm using OkHttp3 to do that, combined with the OkHttp3-sse library (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.0 & com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-sse:4.1.0).
I am able to connect to the server and receive the events just fine, but at some point in time, I want to disconnect the client and shutdown my application. That is were the problem is. The connection gets closed, but the application is not shutting down, probably due to the `ConnectionPool` not closing.

## Attempted:

As there is hardly any documentation on the use of the OkHttp3-sse library, I have tried to reverse engineer from the code what to do. I have tried to:

- call `RealEventSource.cancel()` which is disconnecting, but is hanging on a thread
- call `OkHttpClient.dispatcher().cancelAll()` which is also disconnecting, but remains hanging on a thread
- call `Response.close()` which is passed to `EventSourceListener.onOpen()`

## Finding:

As an alternative, I have looked at https://github.com/heremaps/oksse which has the `RealServerSentEvent.close()` call which is doing what I expect. It closes the connection and stops all threads allowing the application to shutdown completely.
I have looked at the implementation of the `RealServerSentEvent` class to see how the implementation differs from `RealEventSource`. I think the difference is in the conditions of the read loop:

`RealEventSource` line https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-sse/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/sse/RealEventSource.kt#L75:

```
      try {
        listener.onOpen(this, response)
        while (reader.processNextEvent()) {
        }
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        listener.onFailure(this, e, response)
        return
      }
```

compares to
`RealServerSentEvent` line https://github.com/heremaps/oksse/blob/master/src/main/java/com/here/oksse/RealServerSentEvent.java#L94:

```
            listener.onOpen(this, response);

            //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
            while (call != null && !call.isCanceled() && sseReader.read()) {
            }
```

The `OkSSE` implementation includes the condition if the `call.isCanceled()` in the loop, where as the `OkHttp3-sse` does not. I suspect this is causing `OkHttp3-sse` not to exit, but I might be mistaken.

Or, am I overseeing the intended way of disconnecting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually I found the connection can be gracefully shut down by calling:

```
eventSource.cancel();
client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
```

As this does not require any changes to the library, I closed the bug report.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the API correctly and OkHttp should be causing the read to fail with an IOException when the call is canceled. Obviously this isn't happening which I read as a bug in OkHttp.

Next steps: report the bug to OkHttp. If you can do so with an executable test case I'll make sure this gets fixed real soon.

Comment: Well, the IOException does occur and receiving of events has stopped, but the thread seems to remain. The `OkSSE` implementation does not even throw an exception, but gracefully stops and lets the application exit. I'll report the bug asap. Thanks for your quick response!